# Did the prerogative writ of prohibition ever have a Latin name?

Tags: legal-history, legal-terms, from-the-latin

Four of the five prerogative writs are known by their Latin names (*habeas corpus, mandamus, quo warranto, certiorari*), but I have never seen the fifth referred to as anything other than 'prohibition'.  Did this writ ever have a Latin name, and if so, what was it?

Answer (score 5):

I've seen *prohibito* used in a few places, but never by any source that I'd use as a model for my writing.

As I understand it, the Latin names for the other writs were adopted in medieval times, when Latin was much more heavily used in the English courts, while the writ of prohibition developed centuries later. In that case, I think it would have been natural to simply give it a standard English name.